# Put docstrings on special methods?

Tags: python, docstring

I'm trying to decide what information to put in the class docstring and what to put in the `__init__` method docstring. Up until now I've been putting an overview of the class and how to work with it in the class docstring, while stuff directly related to initialization (argument details etc.) I put in the `__init__` docstring.

Today I started wondering if this was the right way of doing it, so I looked at a couple of built-in modules, and I see that the `__init__` method almost never has a docstring. According to PEP8, *"Docstrings are not necessary for non-public methods"*, but isn't  `__init__` public?

In the same vein, what about other special methods, like `__getitem__`, `__getattr__` or `__new__`, should they have docstrings? Or should I just mention the consequences they have in the class docstring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight from [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> Public methods (including the `__init__` constructor) should also have docstrings.

[...]

> The class constructor should be documented in the docstring for its `__init__` method.

Comment: The shame! I thought I'd done my research well, and I miss the obvious place to look. :(